# Ionic 2 animations not working on iOS device

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I have created a project using Ionic 2 sidemenu

```
$ ionic start mySideMenu sidemenu --v2
```

I only wrote down few codes just to test if this works in iOS device/simulator.

**`page1.ts`**

```
import { Component, trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-page1',
    templateUrl: 'page1.html',
    animations: [
        trigger('buttonState', [
            state('left', style({ transform: 'translateX(100px)', backgroundColor: 'red' })),
            state('right', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)', backgroundColor: 'blue' })),
            transition('left <=> right', [
                animate('1000ms ease-in-out')
            ])
        ])
    ]
})
export class Page1 {

    state: string = 'left';

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    changeState() {
        this.state = this.state == 'left' ? 'right': 'left';
    }
}
```

**`page1.html`**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Page One</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Ionic Menu Starter</h3>

  <p>
    If you get lost, the <a href="http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2">docs</a> will show you the way.
  </p>

  <button ion-button secondary [@buttonState]="state" (click)="changeState()">Toggle Menu</button>
</ion-content>
```

Now, after building the app and testing it in the simulator/device, the only thing worked here is the changing of color and position. Not even a single pixel was moved.

It works on android device and not on iOS. I only want to use the built-in animations by Angular. Any thoughts on this how I can make it work on both platform? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since this is not an Angular 2 but an Ionic 2 question, I will lead you how I did it.

Just install **web-animations-js**

```
$ npm install --save web-animations-js
```

Since this is Ionic 2, we don't have **`polyfills.ts`** somewhere in the code. The better place to put it is in the **`main.ts`** file. If you have better idea feel free to comment.

**`main.ts`**

```
import 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min';
```

Then you are good to go. :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in their [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html), the [web animations API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation) is not supported by iOS.

You should add the [animations polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) to your project